# I cant seem to insert data in my database using php with mysql wamp

Tags: php, mysql, database, wampserver

This a sample code for registration a user needs to enter his/her first name, last name, username, email, password and re type his/her password. For some reason I cant insert any data into my database.

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "janrex", "webdev", "cuisine");

if(isset($_POST['SI']))
{
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['f_name']);
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['l_name']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['u_name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
    $pass2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']); 

    if($pass1 == $pass2)
    {
        $sql = mysql_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, uname, email, password) VALUES ('$f_name', '$l_name', '$u_name', '$email', '$pass1')");
        header("location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: error.php");
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: `mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`

Comment: You have the order of the arguments to `mysql_query()` backwards. The query is first, `$db` is second (and optional).

Comment: Your order would be correct if you upgraded to `mysqli`.

Comment: What error you are facing ? Please post here your error.
Also please add "echo mysql_error();" function in your else statement, so that you can come to know where and what issue exist in your script.

Comment: First of all, pelase us mysqli or PDO, don't use mysql anymore. Its deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7. Second, learn about SQL injections and how to prevent them with prepared statements. You can visit http://bobby-tables.com for more information. And: stop storing passwords in plaintext! Use some encryption function. It triggers me quite hard that all people here don't mention such things.

Comment: thanks! I got it one last thing I was able to put another row in my datbase table but there are no data in it except the id.

Comment: Enough guessing around - if you enable error-reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` (add this at the top of the file, directly after `<?php`) and use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to get the *actual* query error, you will most likely find one or more warnings or errors - use those to find the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all validate your MySQL login data. Default MySQL in wamp don't has a password and username is root. Further as Milan stated don't use MySQL functions use mysqli, improved MySQL interface. Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// I prefer using oop
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
// Ofcourse replace them with you own details!

if(isset($_POST['SI'])){
    $firstname = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['f_name']);
    $lastname = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['l_name']);
    $username = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['u_name']);
    $email = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass1 = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
    $pass2 = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']); 

    if($pass1 == $pass2){
        $sql = $mysql->query("INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, uname, email, password) VALUES (\"$firstname\", \"$lastname\", \"$username\", \"$email\", \"$pass1\")");
        header("location: home.php");
    }
    else
        header("location: error.php");
}
```

See if it works for you!

Comment: There are undefined variables on line 17. shoul i remove the slash on the variables?

Comment: And be sure to use security. try hashing data and use security functions;

Comment: use htmlentities($string) to prevent XSS, use hash('ripemd128', $string) to store it in encrypted form and use stripslashes and tags

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: mysql_query in C:\wamp\www\worldcuisine\register.php on line 17

Comment: that error showed up including this one

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\worldcuisine\register.php on line 17

Comment: use $mysql->query() and take back -1

Comment: Thee are no errors anymore but its still not adding data

Comment: Send me full code, along with the page that sends post data. I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code and for Insert values in database

```
     session_start();
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "janrex", "webdev", "cuisine");

    if(isset($_POST['SI']))
    {


      $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['f_name']);
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['l_name']);
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['u_name']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);
        $pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['pass2']); 

    if($pass1 == $pass2)
    {
        $sql = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, uname, email, password) VALUES ('".$f_name."', '".$l_name."', '".$u_name."', '".$email."', '".$pass1."')");
        header("location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: error.php");
    }

}
```

Comment: its adding a row but its not storing any data.

Answer (score 1):

Best way. Go to phpmyadmin 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin or localhost/phpmyadmin (on wamp or xampp) then go to desired table and click insert tab. Then add values as required, then click Go. It will show a query copy that, paste it in your code and replace the data with desired variables.Done!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple problems. You better use mysqli or PDO with prepared statement. Then you can use mysqli_real_scape_string API. Following code is an example of using mysqli with placeholder and prepared statement.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['SI']))
{
    $_user = 'root';
    $_password= 'root';
    $_db = 'localtest'        
    $_host = 'localhost';
    $_port = 3306;

    $link = new mysqli($_host, $_user, $_password, $_db);
    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
       die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

        $firstname = $_POST['f_name'];
        $lastname = $_POST['l_name'];
        $username = $_POST['u_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
        $pass2 = $_POST['pass2']; 
    if($pass1 == $pass2)
    {    
        $stmt = $link-> prepare("INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, uname, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        /* Bind parameters, s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
        $stmt -> bind_param("sssss", $firstname, $lastname, $username, $email, $pass1);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $link->close();
        header("location: home.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: error.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i know why it is happening because i faced the same problem.
you have made an column unique(probably user id column)
when you are inserting a value,a default value is being added to that column.but as the column is unique,it cannot contain two cells with same value.thats preventing you from performing query your command.

just delete the column and try.it will work

Comment: Formatting lacks capital letters, and punctuation spacing is not observed. Considering the comments on the question itself, there are probably multiple issues than the one mentioned in the answer. The answer is a guess - it will better to ask for more details on the problem.